# How to handle System.Data.NoNullAllowedException

Tags: c#, database

I'm having a little problem adding values ​​to the database using the toolStrip add button. I created a tables with some columns, I defined that the field ID can not be null.

But how can I force the user to populate this field without firing the exception? I know the correct use of try catch, however, I do not know where to insert it (in which event)

```
public partial class Controller: Form {
 public Controller() {
  InitializeComponent();
 }

 private void infoBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  this.Validate();
  this.infoBindingSource.EndEdit();
  this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.assinantesDataSet1);

 }

 private void Controller_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'assinantesDataSet1.Info' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
  this.infoTableAdapter.Fill(this.assinantesDataSet1.Info);

 }
}
```

[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ4S8.jpg)

Comment: By validating the user input. How does the user input? How are you building your UI? With WinForm, WPf, webpages...??

Comment: Explain the UI or show any code you've currently got

Comment: @Twyxz u can see image attached

Comment: You can easily put if(ID != "")
{
//(show other fields)
}

Answer (score 0):

Before you try to insert data into the database, validate the data entered by the user, and if it is not valid, notify the user about it.